# How can I plot these variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot my variables for `teta=0:360` degree. But I cant solve matrix problems. Plot all variables such as `vc`, `ac`, `bzegon` ,`bdot`.

```
teta=0:.1:2*pi;
w=2000*2*pi/60;l1=.05;l2=0.15;
beta=asin(l1/l2*sin(teta));
bdot=l1/l2*w*(cos(teta)./sin(beta));
xc=l1*cos.(teta)+l2*cos.(beta);
vc=-l1*w*sin.(teta)-l2*bdot.*sin.(beta);
bzegon=-l*w*(w*sin.(teta)*(xc-l1*cos.(teta))+cos.(teta)*(vc+l1*sin.(teta)))/((xc-l*cos. (teta))^2);
ac=-l1*w*cos.(teta)-l2*bzegon.*sin.(beta)-l2*bdot.*cos.(beta);
plot(teta,bdot);
set(gca,'XTick',0:pi/2:2*pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0','pi/2','pi','3pi/2','2p'})
%title('bdot');
ylabel('bdot');
xlabel('radian');
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
xc=l1*cos.(teta)+l2*cos.(beta);
vc=-l1*w*sin.(teta)-l2*bdot.*sin.(beta);
bzegon=-l*w*(w*sin.(teta)*(xc-l1*cos.(teta))+cos.(teta)*(vc+l1*sin.(teta)))/((xc-l*cos. (teta))^2);
ac=-l1*w*cos.(teta)-l2*bzegon.*sin.(beta)-l2*bdot.*cos.(beta);
```

with:

```
xc=l1*cos(teta)+l2*cos(beta);
vc=-l1*w.*sin(teta)-l2*bdot.*sin(beta);
bzegon=-l1*w.*(w.*sin(teta).*(xc-l1*cos(teta))+cos(teta).*(vc+l1*sin(teta)))/((xc-l1*cos(teta)).^2);
ac=-l1*w.*cos(teta)-l2*bzegon.*sin(beta)-l2*bdot.*cos(beta);
```

You have to check all the parameters once again, maybe I messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code with the `.` operator. You can't do `cos.(beta)`, the `.` operator for element-by-element operation needs to be before things like multiply, add, subtract, raise to the power n, etc... Here's a corrected version of your code (I have assumed a scalar value for `l` which is not specified in your question):

```
teta=0:.1:2*pi;
w=2000*2*pi/60;l1=.05;l2=0.15;
l=l1+l2; % or whatever value, I assumed l was a scalar
beta=asin(l1/l2*sin(teta));
bdot=l1/l2*w*(cos(teta)./sin(beta));
xc=l1*cos(teta)+l2*cos(beta);
vc=-l1*w*sin(teta)-l2*bdot.*sin(beta);
bzegon=-l*w.*(w.*sin(teta).*(xc-l1*cos(teta))+cos(teta).*(vc+l1*sin(teta)))/((xc-l*cos(teta)).^2);
ac=-l1*w.*cos(teta)-l2*bzegon.*sin(beta)-l2*bdot.*cos(beta);
plot(teta,bdot);
set(gca,'XTick',0:pi/2:2*pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0','pi/2','pi','3pi/2','2p'})
%title('bdot');
ylabel('bdot');
xlabel('radian');
```